# Runtime error (NZEC) Python

Tags: python, runtime-error

I am trying a problem which is as follows

```
    Master Shifu is organizing a quiz for Po. The quiz consists of N multiple-choice 
questions, conveniently numbered 0 through N-1. For each question there are three possible answers labeled A, B, and C. For each question, exactly one of the three possible
answers is correct. You are given the information on correct answers as a String answers.
More precisely, answers[i] is the correct answer to the i-th question. This is of course unknown to Po.


    Po did not know the answer to any of the quiz questions. Being desperate, he with some
help from Tigress,Mantis,Crane,Viper and Monkey he got the answer script. However, the only
thing he could obtain was aggregate information on the answers that will be used. More 
precisely, Po now knows how many questions have the answer A, how many have the answer B, 
and how many have the answer C.


    When taking the quiz, Po will be given the questions one at a time, in the same order
that is used in answers. For each of the questions, he will use his intuition to pick one 
of the answers that are still possible. After he picks the answer for a question, Master 
Shifu will tell him the correct answer for that question. Po has noticed that sometimes he 
can rule out some of the answers when answering a question. Your task is to help Po by 
telling him the number of options he will choose from when answering i-th question.

Constraints:

1<=N<=50

Each character of answers will be 'A', 'B', or 'C'.





Input

First line will contain the number of test cases, T. Then T lines follow each containg the string of answers.

Output

Output an array of N numbers, where i-th element will tell the number of options Po will choose from when answering i-th question.
```

The code i wrote in python is

```
from collections import Counter
t = int(raw_input())
for i in range(t):
    po = []
    s = raw_input()
    a = Counter(s)
    options = 3
    for x in s:
        na = a['A']
        nb = a['B']
        nc = a['C']
        if na == 0 or nb == 0 or nc == 0:
            options = 2
        if (na == 0 and nb == 0) or (nb == 0 and nc == 0) or (nc == 0 and na == 0):
            options = 1
        if (na == 0 and nb == 0 and nc == 0):
            options = 0
        po.append(options)
        a[x] -= 1
    out = ""
    for x in po:
        out += str(x) + " "
    print out
```

I am getting Runtime error (NZEC) as i run the code on spoj portal but i correct output on ideone (http://ideone.com/WseoQ)

```
Input:
4
AAAAA
AAABBB
CAAAAAC
BBCA
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are getting the NZEC due to extra white spaces in the input. You can try to take input at once and tokenize it by white spaces.

```
from collections import Counter
import sys
tokenizedInput = sys.stdin.read().split()
t = int(tokenizedInput[0])
for i in range(t):
    po = []
    s = tokenizedInput[i+1]
```

I hope that helps.